# Individual class for each Action Listener?

Tags: java, swing, button, listener, action

My application has 15 different buttons and I've been wondering if it's a good idea to have a individual class for each button listener?
I currently have only one class that handles all buttons using switch/case but it's hard to maintain and read.

I'm not huge fan of using anonymous classes - again because of the readability.

Any suggestions that can help me resolve this issue would be appreciated.

I'm using Java Swing if this matters.

Comment: Have you looked into lambda expressions? They're the alternative to annoymous classes for functional interfaces (interfaces with only 1 method)

Comment: Generally, yes, it's a good idea to have a separate action listener for each JButton.  However, if a group of JButtons are logically grouped, like a 3 x 3 grid of JButtons for a tic-tac-toe game, then it makes sense to have one action listener for the JButtons group.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one class but it is not a good dsign because you need to apply a principle of separation of concerns. You want coherance in a class so that the methods are meaningfull and logical according to the business domain your are dealing with. Also in some cases the same action listener can handle many buttons.

Example: assuming I am building a calculator. I know that the behavior of operators is similar when they are clicked on. And so is it with the digits buttons. Therefore I can have some classes, let's say

```
public class OperationActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Handle what happens when the user click on +, -, * and / buttons
    }
}


public class DigitActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Handle what happens when the user click on a digit button
    }
}
```

etc.

Now in my user interface I will add an instance of the same action listener

```
JButton buttonPlus = new JButton("+")
JButton buttonMinus = new JButton("-");
...

JButton buttonOne = new JButton("1");
JButton buttonTwo = new JButton("2"); 
...

OperationActionListener operationListener = new OperationActionListener();
DigitActionListener digitListener = new DigitsActionListener();

buttonPlus.addActionListener(operationListener);
buttonMinus.addActionListener(operationListener);
....

buttonOne.addActionListener(digitListener);
buttonTwo.addActionListener(digitListener);
....
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So it is not a problem to have multiple classes? In my case almost all buttons must change the user interface and I have to pass an instance of the frame to the listener so I can make the changes. Something like that: `someButton.addActionListener( new ButtonListener(this) );` Will this cause performance problems?

Comment: No having multiple classes is not a problem in itself. But designing classes should always be carrefully done. Instead of doing a `new ButtonListener(this)`when you add the action listener on each button, do it once and for all with `ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener(this)`and then `someButton.addActionListener(listener)`and someButton2.addActionListener(listener). This way the same listener is reused.

Comment: Can you explain to me what's the difference between using anonymous object instantiation and creating non anonymous object ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @kraikov you will generally use anonymous object instanciation when you are sure that you will not need to use it anywhere else. It's a one shot deal! You have no way to reuse the anonymous class somewhere else, since if you try to copy past the same creation code it will instanciate a new object. There are case when it is usefull: you don't want to bother yourself will managing a class. example you want to use the mouseClicked event from the MouseAdapter only once and for all

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the same listener being used by multiple buttons:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class CalculatorPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JTextField display;

    public CalculatorPanel()
    {
        Action numberAction = new AbstractAction()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
//              display.setCaretPosition( display.getDocument().getLength() );
                display.replaceSelection(e.getActionCommand());
            }
        };

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        display = new JTextField();
        display.setEditable( false );
        display.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        add(display, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(0, 5) );
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            String text = String.valueOf(i);
            JButton button = new JButton( text );
            button.addActionListener( numberAction );
            button.setBorder( new LineBorder(Color.BLACK) );
//          button.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(50, 50) );
            buttonPanel.add( button );

            InputMap inputMap = button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(text), text);
            inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("NUMPAD" + text), text);
            button.getActionMap().put(text, numberAction);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        UIManager.put("Button.margin", new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10) );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.add( new CalculatorPanel() );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```